# Why does assigning a variable with command substitution, and then echoing that variable, always fail?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

Why does the following not work in Bash?

```bash
# Ensure TEST is unset
export TEST=''
echo "Hello world!" > test.txt && TEST="$(cat test.txt)" echo "$TEST"
```

It always returns a blank line for some reason.

Doing it on separate lines gives the expected result:

```bash
# Ensure TEST is unset
export TEST=''
echo "Hello world" > test.txt
TEST=$(cat test.txt)
echo "$TEST"
Hello world!
```

How can I make this work in a one-liner?

I need this to decrypt a [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) file containing a string with special characters which I then pass to [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)).

```
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD="$( gpg -d ~/gpg_encrypted_vault_password_file 2>/dev/null )" ansible-playbook etc etc etc
```

For some reason, Ansible developers think storing a vault password in a plain text file is secure
and I don't like typing (or copy-pasting) long secure passwords every time I test a play, so using the GPG agent with an encrypted file is the only secure workaround that I can come up with.

Comment: "for some reason ansible devs think storing a vault-password in a plain text file is secure" – They give you another option. Use the "If executable, it will be run and the resulting stdout will be used as the password" description of `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE`. This will be like `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=/path/to/file ansible-playbook …` where `/path/to/file` is an *exectuable* script that will run `gpg -d ~/gpg_encrypted_vault_password_file 2>/dev/null`. Not tested because I have not and I do not use `ansible-playbook`, I have just skimmed through the documentation.

Comment: On a side note: On Linux the initial environment for a process is visible to other processes under the same user through the `/proc/` file system. A password passed this way is just as exposed as a if it were stored in a plaintext file with owner-only read permissions.

Comment: TEST="$(cat test.txt)" and  echo "$TEST" are two separate commands. Try separating them with a semicolon.

Comment: \**[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not to conflict with any of the other pre-existing answers, but I thought a step-by-step analysis may help.  ([u1686_grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1836831/401839) looks accurate, but I thought this might be more clear...)

`# ensure TEST is unset
export TEST=''`

Good news: This likely works as you expected.  The # turns the first line into a comment, and then the next line makes the TEST variable have an empty string (zero bytes).

`echo "Hello world!" > test.txt && TEST="$(cat test.txt)" echo "$TEST"`

The shell notices the &&.  It will run the first portion of the code...

`echo "Hello world!" > test.txt`

Then, it processes the &&.  It looks at the return value of the echo command, and sees that it is zero.  Therefore, it can proceed to run the second command.  The second command is:

`TEST="$(cat test.txt)" echo "$TEST"`

So, the first thing the shell is going to do here is to replace the variables.  The "command substitution" acts like a variable here, so the "cat text.txt" command runs.  In the shell's perspective, the command now looks more like:

`TEST="Hello world!" echo "$TEST"`

Now, that all probably looks good so far, but here's the big issue.  The shell doesn't start running the '`TEST="Hello world!"`' command yet.  Instead, the shell notices that there is still a reference to `$TEST`, so the shell replaces that.

Now, the command that the shell plans to run looks something like this:

`TEST="Hello world!" echo ""`

I suppose that if I'm going to go into some full detail, I will point out that the shell does perform the act of breaking this command into pieces.  This action removes the quotation marks.  So the individual pieces look like this:

1. TEST
2. =
3. Hello world!
4. echo
5. (empty value)

Okay, now the shell finally is done replacing things, so it can go onto the next task, which is to find what executable code to run.

It notices that the command line starts with a form of `A=B C` (where `A` represents a variable name, the equal sign specifies that a variable will be assigned a value, and `B` represents the value to be assigned, and then `C` is an optional portion which represents a command to run.

When the shell notices the command line fits this general pattern, the executable code that it is going to run is the code that handles the equal sign.  Basically, the equal sign is similar to an executable filename, in the sense that the equal sign ends up controlling what code the shell is going to be executing.  The shell proceeds to execute the code to assign a variable named `TEST` to have a value of `Hello world!`.

Then, after that is done, the shell will start the requested command, which uses the 4th and 5th potions identified above (where the 4th portion is the `echo` command, and the 5th portion is the empty string).

The reason that i's answer (err...  I mean, [sqrt-1's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1836828/401839)) works is that the second && causes the shell to run the `TEST="$(cat test.txt)"` code's return value is, notice that is zero, and only then proceed to process what comes after the second `&&` (so then the `echo "$TEST"` portion will have the `$TEST` variable processed, and by now it all works).

Note that sqrt-1's provided answer shows some code that is a little bit wasteful, although understandably so because it does directly answer the asked question.  What it basically does is:

First, splits the command into three parts:

echo "Hello world!" > test.txt

TEST="$(cat test.txt)"

echo "$TEST"

The third part only runs if the second part (runs and) succeeds, and the second part only runs if the first command succeeds, because of the two `&&` operators.

Another variation could be:

`echo "Hello world!" > test.txt && ( TEST="$(cat test.txt)" ; echo "$TEST" )`

With that semi-colon, the results of the '`TEST="$(cat test.txt)"`' will not be evaluated to determine whether the '`echo "$TEST"' will be run.  When I see a &&`, I tend to try to figure out what is going to be evaluated, and why that would matter.  So, despite the added complexity of needing to use parenthesis, this variation with a semi-colon actually seems to me like it may be a bit simpler to mentally process.

Comment: As a potentially fun/enlightening excercise, consider this: `mkdir -p t/u/v ; cd t/u ; echo t2.txt >> v/t2.txt ; echo From $(pwd) ; find . -iname t*.txt ; echo t1.txt >> t1.txt ; echo From $(pwd) ; find . -iname t*.txt ; cd .. ; echo From $(pwd) ; find . -iname t*.txt ` ; # and then figure out, why doesn't the t2.txt show up when you run the "find" command from the t/u sub-directory?  And then, what causes the file to re-appear in the final "find" command?

Comment: Note that your use of `(`...`)` will run the variable assignment in a subshell, and the result will not be visible afterwards, while using `{`...`;}` would allow the variable to be assigned in the same shell, although in this simple case it won't make any difference.

Comment: You might want to mention `set -x` as a way for the user to see all this happening.

Answer (score 25):

It doesn't work because `$var` expansions are performed by the shell before the command line is run, i.e. **not** by the 'echo' command.

Meanwhile, `VAR=value somecommand` is not a regular assignment – it is only meant to inject an environment variable into the new process, but has no effect on shell variables before that process is created, i.e. it is completely different from `VAR=value; somecommand`.

So in other words, it happens in the opposite order than what your post's title describes. First the (stil-empty) `"$TEST"` is expanded into `""`, **then** `echo ""` is run with an additional `TEST=...` environment variable which it does not care about.

Since your test commands are supposed to imitate the behavior of Ansible, they should be actually looking at *their* environment variables and not relying on pre-expansion by the shell; something like `VAR=value env` or `VAR=value printenv VAR` would be a much better fit.

Answer (score 20):

#### Why does the following not work in bash?

```
echo "Hello world!" > test.txt && TEST="$(cat test.txt)" echo "$TEST"
```

If you run it though [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) it will tell you why:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 2:
echo "Hello world!" > test.txt && TEST="$(cat test.txt)" echo "$TEST"
                                  ^-- SC2097 (warning): This assignment is only seen by the forked process.
>>                                                             ^-- SC2098 (warning): This expansion will not see the mentioned assignment.
```

See [ShellCheck: SC2097 – This assignment is only seen by the forked process.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2097)

Answer (score -2):

Based on the link provided by @DavidPostill, I would use

```
echo "Hello world!" > test.txt && TEST="$(cat test.txt)" && echo "$TEST"
```

**DUE EDIT**
As many users rightly pointed out, mine is far to be a useful answer: It allows no one to learn anything about the topic.
**Please, refer instead to @TOOGAM's [post](https://superuser.com/a/1836956/1898068)** below, which is the best answer (my personal opinion) and fully exposes why @Peter Mortensen's code doesn't work, how bash variabile expansion works and even why my use of a second `&&` Is not the optimal choice.

Comment: That works.....

Comment: While this works, it doesn't actually answer the question... The question is why it doesn't work rather than how to make it work

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how your solution fixes it.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater and @ Barmar, you're absolutely right, my bad.
Fortunately, @ TOOGAM posted an [outstanding answer](https://superuser.com/a/1836956/1898068) !!! By far the best one (my opinion)

Comment: Yep, and unfortunately SO still lacks a way for the community to override the accepted answer

Comment: As someone who doesn't know Bash, I had to rechecked the question at least twice before figuring out the difference (the second `&&`). I think that says more or less about how this answer is useful for beginners.